# How to create simple area series in wp8 using sparrow charts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, data-visualization

I need to create an area series chart for my wp8 app. So I decided to use sparrow toolkit for it, but unfortunately there do sent seem to be any tutorials for it on the web. I am just looking on how to start with it.. so if anyone can give a basic explanation or point me to a decent tutorial that would be great.

And if anyone knows of a better tool to achieve this please tell me about it ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

B0rn2C0de, I feel your pain creating charts for the Windows Phone.

Here is a simple example of what you want.

Data = X axis value, Value = Y axis value

[XAML]

```
<sparrow:SparrowChart Height="400" Width="400">                
    <sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
        <sparrow:LinearXAxis/>
    </sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
    <sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
        <sparrow:LinearYAxis/>
    </sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
    <sparrow:AreaSeries Fill="Red" Stroke="White">
        <sparrow:AreaSeries.Points>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="0" Value="1"/>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="1" Value="2"/>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="2" Value="1"/>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="3" Value="4"/>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="4" Value="0"/>
        </sparrow:AreaSeries.Points>
    </sparrow:AreaSeries>
</sparrow:SparrowChart>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks .. that really helped :) .. one more thing i couldnt do was add a time asix to it .. what would be the type of point to add to it ?