# Sparrow toolkit

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sparrow-framework

```
<sparrow:SparrowChart Height="400" Width="400">                
<sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
    <sparrow:LinearXAxis/>
</sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
<sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
    <sparrow:LinearYAxis/>
</sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
<sparrow:AreaSeries Fill="Red" Stroke="White">
    <sparrow:AreaSeries.Points>
        <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="0" Value="1"/>
        <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="1" Value="2"/>
        <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="2" Value="1"/>
        <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="3" Value="4"/>
        <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="4" Value="0"/>
    </sparrow:AreaSeries.Points>
</sparrow:AreaSeries>
```

[image]

How do I erase the parallel lines from 0.8,1.6... from x axis and y axis?

Answer (score 1):

Hehe, that's my code and picture you got from [Sparrow Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962187/how-to-create-simple-area-series-in-wp8-using-sparrow-charts/24967296#24967296)

To erase the vertical lines in the fill, just set the stroke to the same color as the fill like so.  To get rid of grid lines you need to set some styles up.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Line" x:Key="crossLineStyle">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#00000000"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Line" x:Key="axisLineStyle">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#00000000"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Line" x:Key="minorcrossLineStyle">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#00000000"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0.25"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>



<sparrow:SparrowChart Height="400" Width="400">
    <sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>

        <sparrow:LinearXAxis CrossLineStyle="{StaticResource crossLineStyle}" MinorLineStyle="{StaticResource minorcrossLineStyle}" MajorLineStyle="{StaticResource crossLineStyle}" AxisLineStyle="{StaticResource axisLineStyle}"/>
    </sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
    <sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
        <sparrow:LinearYAxis CrossLineStyle="{StaticResource crossLineStyle}" MinorLineStyle="{StaticResource minorcrossLineStyle}" MajorLineStyle="{StaticResource crossLineStyle}" AxisLineStyle="{StaticResource axisLineStyle}"/>
    </sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
    <sparrow:AreaSeries Fill="Red" Stroke="Red">
        <sparrow:AreaSeries.Points>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="0" Value="1"/>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="1" Value="2"/>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="2" Value="1"/>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="3" Value="4"/>
            <sparrow:DoublePoint Data="4" Value="0"/>
        </sparrow:AreaSeries.Points>
    </sparrow:AreaSeries>
</sparrow:SparrowChart>
```

---

[image]