# Drawing Control for Windows Phone 8.1 (universal app)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, canvas, drawing, windows-phone-8.1

There are any Drawing Control for Windows Phone 8.1 (universal app)?

I want to drawing chart on windows phone 8.1 but i need some libraries to help me to do that.

I prefer to be free library.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik UI for Windows Universal debuting with a Powerful Chart Library

[Telerik UI for Windows Universal debuting with a Powerful Chart Library](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/14-08-07/telerik-ui-for-windows-universal-debuting-with-a-powerful-chart-library)

---

Try WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization on NuGet or I think it's home page is here.

[WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

---

Old Answer:

There are a few charting libraries you can get from NuGet:

Here are my favorites:

- Sparrow Chart [Sparrow Toolkit Home](https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/)
- amCharts
- Quick Charts

I have a easy example of Sparrow Chart xaml here: [Simple Charting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962187/how-to-create-simple-area-series-in-wp8-using-sparrow-charts/24967296#24967296)

And if you're adventurous it's not that difficult to draw a grid and some points/fill with the
`<canvas>` tag.

Comment: thanks,but unfortunately all these libraries don't support Windows Phone 8.1 Platform (Universal app),can you help me ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question.  Check out WinRT XAML Toolkit for universal charting.  I updated the solution.

Comment: also unfortunately its doesn't supported Windows Phone 8.1 just windows 8.1

Comment: Ah I see, then would you be okay with something that isn't really tested out that much? Telerik UI

Comment: Do check out the latest source code of the WinRT XAML Toolkit, because if I'm not mistaken it's already been ported to work with universal apps ( there is a shared winrt - wp rt project now ) - the normal download is still an older version! So download source code and build it yourself.